# Reopen Activity with Fade In and Fade Out Animation in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-animation

**WHAT I HAVE**

I have an app with dynamic theming support. Everything works very well, but now while changing the themes I want to give it a fade-in and fade-out effect to make the theme changing transition look seamless.

**WHAT I HAV TRIED**

1) I have tried to `recreate()` the activity, but that doesn't apply any animations.

2) I have added a window animations, like this,

```
<style name="WindowFadeTransition">
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/WindowAnimationTransition</item>
    </style>

    <style name="WindowAnimationTransition">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@android:anim/fade_in</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@android:anim/fade_out</item>
    </style>
```

And I have applied the style in my activity.

I re-open the activity using,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsThemeActivity.class);
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
getActivity().finish();
```

The animation works really well, but there is a problem.

**THE BUG**

As I have applied the window animation to the activity itself, whenever I open and close the activity, the animation triggers, which is not what I want. I want the animation to work only when I am changing theme and calling the above lines of code to re-open the activity.

I know it's kind of tricky. How to fix this issue? Any ideas?

Comment: Try this After startActivity(); call overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in,R.anim.fade_out);

Comment: How will that help btw? I already have sliding animation on the activity when it opens and closes. So, can't use overridePendingTransition().

Comment: You are saying that you need to have animation only when activaty is called! Did you try removing <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@android:anim/fade_out</item>

Comment: Really? Have you read the question carefully?

Comment: Here is what you said---> As I have applied the window animation to the activity itself, whenever I open and close the activity, the animation triggers, // you said that it triggers both when activity open and close// which is not what I want. I want the animation to work only when I am changing theme and calling the above lines of code to re-open the activity. //you said when you reopen the activity

Comment: It's working. You can put it as an answer, I will accept it,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this After startActivity(); call `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in,R.anim.fade_out);`

Comment: The actual solution was to use overridePendingTransactions for this.

Comment: See I told you at first! No worries! I have edited the answer!! Check it